# Storing a dictionary inside SqlAlchemy models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy model named user:

```
class User (db.Model):
    id = id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)

    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I want to have a dictionary attribute inside this model (class).
Am I able to do something like this:

```
class User (db.Model):
    id = id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    messages = {}    # a dictionary which maps each category to a list of msgs

    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name

    def append_msg (msg, category):
        self.messages[category].append (msg)
```

What is the best way to implement this structure?
Is this dictionary permanent or It is temporary in memory?

Answer (score 0):

sqlalchemy has JSON with it.

```
from sqlalchemy import JSON
class User (db.Model):
    id = id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    messages = db.Column(JSON) #or may be db.Column(db.JSON)
```

It would be there in your DB.